# How to determine whether all possible linear combinations of u and v form a line or a plane.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I just started learning linear algebra and I'm not sure how to determine whether all possible linear combinations of $u$ and $v$ form a line or a plane.

For example I was given a vector $u=<2,1,3>$ and $v=<8,4,12>$ and was asked to determine if they form a line or a plane. Can someone please explain how you would do this. Thank you.

Comment: If ${\bf u} \neq k {\bf v}$, they are not parallel and hence define a plane.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are working in $\mathbb{R}^3$, so you can think geometrically about this. Two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ span a line if and only if they are parallell and  at least of them is non-zero. Otherwise (provided *both* are non-zero), they span a plane.

PS: I strongly encourage you to adopt a different notation for vectors. $(x,y,z)$ or $[x, y,z]$ is highly preferable compared to $< x,y,z >$, which in the two-dimensional case is confusingly similar to the notation for an inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$.

Comment: Yes, I will thank you!

Comment: No problem - glad to help!